# Import newly generated address to bitcoin core

Tags: transactions, blockchain, bitcoin-core, bitcoind, json-rpc

Can I import newly generated address to Bitcoin core with "importaddress" rescan false, for the watch only purpose?

why do I need to rescan if the address doesn't have any history?

Question: will it trigger the "walletnotify" if it receives new transaction on that address without rescanning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why do I need to rescan if the address doesn't have any history?

It does not know it has no history until it completes the rescan.

You can either pass a `false` as extra argument (look up the `importaddress` documentation), or use the more powerful `importmulti` command with a recent birth time.